# Storing numbers as initial values in formik, react-final-form, react-hook-form

Tags: formik, react-hook-form, react-final-form

I am wondering folks thoughts on this scenario: you have an input that represents a price of an item, like filling out a form for an item that users purchase. you have a few utilities to have the number have a certain number of decimals, not be negative, etc. Of course the value in the input itself needs to be a string, since it's html at the end of the day. what would be some benefits/drawbacks for both options:

- write some code that accepts an initial value of type number, and have the number formatted into the string representation, and then parsed back into the number representation, and both things handle potentially converting from value in cents to dollars, etc.
  OR
- format the initial value into a string, and deal with the string value going forward, then on submit to api, parse it to the value that the api needs(in this case value in cents)

I feel like there are tradeoffs to both approaches, but that keeping things as a string always is more decoupled, which comes with some extra code in places like the submit, validation(checking if the value is greater than 0 for example, have to convert to number before validating), but keeps things simple at the form level.

The flipside is if you have a price input field in a lot of places in your app, it may make more sense to do the work of maintaining the number as the value in the form state, and being able to just submit the form state to the api without worrying that it's the right type/value sounds nice and convenient.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day, the DOM inputs work with strings. Historically form data was submitted as query parameters, remember.

React Final Form has had `parse` and `format` props from Day 1, but in my experience, I would advise against using them. My recommendation: Keep your form values strings, and parse them into `Number`s, if you must, at the time of submission.

Comment: thank you for your thoughts!!!  this is my opinion as well.

Comment: Totally agree with Erik's option above.

Answer (score 0):

Input return string by default. You can refer to the spec below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

However, you can use `valueAsNumber`, but you need to be careful with `NaN`. When a parse is failing it will fall back to that.

`valueAsNumber`

double: Returns the value of the element, interpreted as one of the following, in order:

- A time value
- A number
- NaN if conversion is impossible

Here is an implementation in `react-hook-form`, you can also do parse like what Erik (author of React Final Form and Redux Form) suggested above.

```
<input type="number" name="number" ref={register({ valueAsNumber: true, min: 4 })} />
```

All those libs that you have pinged all support one way or another to parse to number.

Comment: I totally see how to do it in the various libraries, but I am more wondering about peoples thoughts in general, like just because you can do it, should you?